# Изменение css элемента svg

Tags: jquery, svg, css, javascript

Задача - после построения svg картинки, с помощью JS/Jquery изменять css выбранного объекта svg. Проблема в Chrome.

Вот этот код работает в Opera, FF и даже IE! Но Chrome не реагирует на это - html код изменяется, но изменения в объекте не происходят.

```
var item=document.getElementById(id);
item.style.fill='#ff0000';
```

Comment: Пример на jsfiddle или в виде сниппета можно увидеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function doIt() {
  var item=document.getElementById("smth");
  item.style.fill='#FF0000';
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle id="smth" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>
<button onclick="doIt()">Do it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так вы используете jQuery или нет? Попробуйте

```
$('#id').attr('fill', '#ff0000');
```

Или что-то такое

```
var item=document.getElementById(id);
item.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
```

Честно, я не проверял, но мало ли)

Comment: Пробовал, результат тот же самый. html меняется, изображение остается прежним.

Comment: а если так: $('#id').prop('fill', '#ff0000');  ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doIt() {
  var item=document.getElementById("smth");
  item.setAttribute('fill', '#FF0000');
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle id="smth" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>
<button onclick="doIt()">Do it</button>
```